# Getting Google Drive to open in a certain folder?

Tags: google-drive

I have a certain folder in Google Drive which contains most of my work materials and which I use many times more often than any other folder. How can I get it to go to that folder by default when I open Google Drive? I used to have it set up this way when it was still Google Documents, but then they changed it and it stopped working, and I can't seem to find whatever it was I changed all those years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it seems to be impossible in Google Drive. The only way that comes to my mind would be to open the folder in Google Drive and then bookmark it.